# How to convert asp.net website with sql server to .EXE file using visual studios

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database, visual-studio-2010, exe

I need to convert asp.net website with sql database integration in to .exe file in visual studios (2010). How to do it ??? shall i require third party tool to convert into .exe

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to create a executable version of an asp.net website. These executables start a webserver on the localhost which serves the website.

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/142022/Creating-exe-for-ASP-net-Web-application

Comment: we had tried with this articles but doesn't worked for me. Required any third party tool to convert into .EXE